# Unit testing of Angular app in Azure DevOps pipeline timing out

Tags: angular, unit-testing, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up testing of our Angular app in an Azure DevOps pipeline, but am running into trouble with unit testing timing out.  This is in a Linux virtual machine, with the chromedriver npm package installed (`npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download --include_chromium`).  Below is the error I am seeing (I tried increasing the timeout period, but it still times out):

```
INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless has not captured in 180000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (1/2).
WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless has not captured in 180000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (2/2).
WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless has not captured in 180000 ms, killing.
ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

The `CHROME_BIN` environment variable is set correctly via:

```
export CHROME_BIN=<project-path>/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver
```

Testing then then started with:

```
ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --reporters=junit --code-coverage
```

Is the chromedriver sufficient to run unit tests on an Angular app?  Do I need to install something else?  Is there any way to tell if testing is even happening?

Comment: Try following this guide: https://qarunqb.medium.com/set-up-your-next-angular-9-project-for-ci-cd-on-bitbucket-pipelines-a024f6c2a2e9 and adding those flags for `karma` (the flags being `--no-sandbox`, `--disable-gpu`).